# Newbie SQL: How to fetch rows *not* included in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having trouble understand JOINs. I have a list of people, and a list of attacks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | johnny |
|    2 | pete   |
|    3 | sally  |
|    4 | paul   |
|    5 | jen    |
|    6 | alan   |
+------+--------+

SELECT * FROM attacks;
+------------+----------+
| attackerId | victimId |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        2 |   (johnny attacked pete)
|          1 |        4 |   (johnny attacked paul)
|          1 |        6 |   (johnny attacked alan)
|          3 |        5 |   (sally attacked jen)
+------------+----------+
```

Could anybody help me figure out what command gets people *not* attacked by johnny like this?

```
+-------+
| name  | 
+-------+
| sally |
| jen   |
+-------+
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN`, `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE`.

Comment: Another hint: you can join to the same table more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Name FROM People
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT VictimID FROM Attacks
                 WHERE AttackerId= 1) AND ID<>1
```

Comment: This works, and the simplest answer, thank you. As a side note I'm guessing that it cannot be achieved without a second SELECT statement, since all of the offered solutions contain one. Does that mean that this particular query will be very slow?

Comment: Obviously the simplest answer(already +1'd it). Only problem is that the `id` of the attacker should be known which won't be case in majority of the Real time scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to this link. Basically is the same question i think

[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

In your case you want to do an outer join

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Left join` here. Also, you can change the `name` in subquery and get results for any other attackers.

```
select p.name
from people p
left join attacks a
on p.id = a.victimId
where 
name <> 'johnny'
and (a.attackerId not in (select id from people
                           where name = 'johnny'
                          )
     or a.attackerId is null
    )
;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dc4f7/5/0)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, because if I change "<> 'johnny'" to "<> 'pete'" I would expect to get johnny, sally, paul, jen and alan but I only get three results (jen, johnny, sally).

Comment: you need to change the name in subquery too. It'll work.  See here :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dc4f7/14/0

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM PEOPLE AS P
INNER JOIN ATTACKER AS A ON P.Id = A.AttackerId
WHERE P.AttackerId != 1;

The above query will return you every row where the attacker is not Id 1(In your case "Johnny").

Comment: It won't return `sally`

Comment: Downvoted because this answer does not answer the stated requirement.

Comment: My bad. Indeed, this answer is not complete. The answer of NiveaGM seems more appopriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`.

**Query**

```
select `name` from `table_1` ta
where not exists(
    select 1 from (
        select t1.`name` as `attacker`, t3.`name` as `victim`
        from `table_1` t1
        join `table_2` t2
        on t1.`id` = t2.`attackerId`
        join `table_1` t3
        on t3.`id` = t2.`victimId`
    ) tb
    where ta.`name` = tb.`victim`
    and tb.`attacker` = 'johnny'
)
and `name` <> 'johnny';
```

**[Find a fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e547f/1)**